# "X11 wrong authorisation protocol attempted" with opengl and sdl over ssh

Tags: opengl, ssh, sdl, x11, x11-forwarding

I've followed a few tutorials on setting up Xming and putty, and also trying with cygwin but there is one particular C progam from a raspberry pi I'm having issues with over ssh to my windows machine. I've been somewhat successful as I can get Pygame and a few other small things to show up on my desktop. I'm now trying to do the same thing with the C program that uses SDL and OpenGL packages. When I try to run the program through ssh I get `init_sdl() PuTTY X11 proxy: wrong authorisation protocol attempted`
I also get the same error when trying to run it with MobaXterm.
at one point I did get `init_sdl()` without the error, but there should be two more lines that follow after that and then a GUI appear, and it isn't happening. So I think it's hanging on trying to initialize sdl? I'm not really sure. Are there any other resources I need for my windows side client?

If needed, here's the program I'm trying to run. It does work on the pi, just not over ssh. https://github.com/bear24rw/rgb_table/tree/master/code/table_drivers/beat_finder

Update: I can get `init_sdl()` to show every time now without the error following in cygwin, but still not getting a GUI to show or get the the full readout of

`init_sdl()
 init_gl()
 init_fft()
 init_serial()` which is what should show.

EDIT2: There is a `use_gui = TRUE/FALSE;` option in the code, when I set this to false, I get `init_fft()` and `init_serial()` and the code works, but I would still like to have what's missing with SDL or GL to get the GUI part to work over SSH.

Comment: Anyone? I'm still stuck.